# Existence of certain multiplicative orders in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given the ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, we can consider the group of units $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$, which has order $\varphi(m)$, where $\varphi$ is the totient function. It then follows from Lagrange's Theorem that the order of any element in said group must divide $\varphi(m)$ (this is Euler's Theorem).

My question concerns a partial converse. Given a $d$ dividing $\varphi(m)$, does there exist a unit $x \not \equiv 1$ such that $x^d \equiv 1$ (mod $m$)? In other words, is there a $d$-th root of unity for any such $d$? I have tried using group theory to answer this question by looking for guaranteed subgroups of order $d$ to little effect, and am hoping someone can find a simple number theoretic solution.

Comment: This is a nice question and it admits a full resolution.  You need $m$ to be $2$, $4$, $p^k$ with $p$ odd prime and $k\geq 1$ or $2p^k$ with $p$ odd prime and $k\geq 1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Oh sorry! I didn't see this comment. I can delete my answer if you want to post the answer.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, no problem your answer has something more than my simple comment (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this doesn't hold for powers of $2$. For $k>2$, we have that $$(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^\times\cong C_2\times C_{2^{k-2}}$$ which doesn't have any elements of order $\varphi(2^k)=2^{k-1}$. Your conjecture is true precisely when $m$ is: $2,4,p^k,$ or $2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

As indicated in the comments, you can read about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) (check out the subsection "Structure")